# How to replace content in image container with new content onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Giphy's API to learn how to make a random GIF generator. The code below works fine for generating one GIF and putting it in the `imageContainer`, but I'm wondering what I can add to make a new GIF appear in the `imageContainer` when the `randomDog` button is clicked? As it looks now, the request for more GIFs is successful if you click the button, but they are not posted in the image container since there is already a GIF in it.

This is my JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open('GET', 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&tag=cute+dog', true);

document.getElementById("randomDog").onclick = function () {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
        data = JSON.parse(request.responseText).data.image_url;
        console.log(data);
        document.getElementById("imageContainer").innerHTML = '<center><img src = "'+data+'"  title="GIF via Giphy"></center>';
    } else {
        console.log('reached giphy, but API returned an error');
     }
};

request.onerror = function() {
    console.log('connection error');
};

request.send();
});
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dogstyle.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sadness be gone!</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="headers">
        <h1> Having a bad day?</h1>
        <h1> Not anymore! </h1>
    </div>

    <h3 id="subheader">Happiness and fluffyness is just a click away</h3>

    <div id="imageContainer"></div>

    <button id="randomDog" class="button">Click away!</button>

    <script src="js/experiment.js"></script>

</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just move the request into the onclick handler

Comment: Would it not be much more simple to give the image tag an `ID`, target the `ID` and change the `src`? `document.getElementById("ImageID").src=data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the lines initializing and sending the `XMLHttpRequest` inside of the `click` handler, and include the success function inside an `onreadystatechange` event handler.

(Note that the API key you are using returns an error for me when I use it in a snippet; unsure of how I would fix that but maybe it will work on your end.)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  document.getElementById("randomDog").onclick = function() {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.open('GET', 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&tag=cute+dog', true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState === 4) {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
          data = JSON.parse(request.responseText).data.image_url;
          console.log(data);
          document.getElementById("imageContainer").innerHTML = '<center><img src = "' + data + '"  title="GIF via Giphy"></center>';
        } else {
          console.log('reached giphy, but API returned an error');
        }
      }
    }
    request.onerror = function() {
      console.log('connection error');
    };

    request.send();
  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dogstyle.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Sadness be gone!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="headers">
    <h1> Having a bad day?</h1>
    <h1> Not anymore! </h1>
  </div>

  <h3 id="subheader">Happiness and fluffyness is just a click away</h3>

  <div id="imageContainer"></div>

  <button id="randomDog" class="button">Click away!</button>

  <script src="js/experiment.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
....    
document.getElementById("randomDog").onclick = function () {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
            data = JSON.parse(request.responseText).data.image_url;
            console.log(data);
            // Clear the existing image first
            document.getElementById("imageContainer").removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName("mygif")[0]);
            // Now set the new image in image container
            document.getElementById("imageContainer").innerHTML = '<center><img class="mygif" src = "'+data+'"  title="GIF via Giphy"></center>';
        } else {
            console.log('reached giphy, but API returned an error');
         }
    };
....
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! ^^

Comment: If my answer solved your query, can you mark it as "answer"?